# script is ignoring Popen method

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python script that writes a couple of different shell scripts and then executes them.  Everything works fine with the exception of one command and I can't figure out why.  When I execute the exact command in the terminal it works perfectly, but it seems like the script is just ignoring it.  The command uses Imagemagick to convert a pdf file to a .png file

I'm on a Mac and as I've said I tried running the command in terminal and it works. I've even tried taking the command out of the shell script and doing it that way.

This command works fine.  It changes the permissions on one of my files so that the script can be executed

```py
subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash chmod +x clearSH.sh',shell=True)
```

This command seems to be totally ignored.  But when I run it manually it works fine.

```py
subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash magick convert -flatten -density 300 phys_kin_posvel1/phys-kin-posvel1_1.pdf -quality 90 phys_kin_posvel1/testpic.png',shell=True)
```

There are no errors thrown, it just seems to be ignoring the command.

Comment: You're not specifying a directory location for the file to change permissions on. Maybe try specifying the full path?

Comment: What kind of programming language would Python be if it randomly ignored the code you've written?! Have you checked the state of the `Popen` object with `obj = subprocess.Popen(...); print(obj)`?

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.Popen` takes a list of arguments.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(['magick', '-flatten', '-density', '300', 'phys_kin_posvel1/phys-kin-posvel1_1.pdf', '-quality 90 phys_kin_posvel1/testpic.png'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

*And also make sure you should use absolute path instead of relative path.*